# Word embedding as features for classification

Tags: nlp, text-classification, word-embedding

W.r.t text classification, now a common approach is to combine (often sum or average) word embeddings and use the result vector as features.

Are there any reference document(s) that establish the comparison of this approach for text classification over traditional feature engineering approaches? [Comparison based on accuracy] [could be on popular datasets like IMDB, sentiment-140 etc]

Answer (score 0):

Compiling a list of potential resources on it:

1. "Word Embeddings and Their Use In Sentence Classification Tasks" by Amit Mandelbaum and Adi Shalev. https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.08229